# How to link scm with any other branch than master on sonarqube?

Tags: github, version-control, sonarqube

while executing the below command

`/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.6.2.2472_1/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=././vendor -Dsonar.login=adfafdsafasweq3e  -Dsonar.host.url=https://abc.xyz.net -Dsonar.links.scm=https://git.com/abc/sonarqube-example-python.git -Dsonar.projectName=xyz:xyz -Dsonar.projectKey=Sonarqube:Python:integration -Dsonar.branch.name=integration -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.c.file.suffixes=- -Dsonar.cpp.file.suffixes=- -Dsonar.objc.file.suffixes=-`

[image]

scm link does not get added on the created sonarqube project, but if i change the branch as to master as below

`/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.6.2.2472_1/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=././vendor -Dsonar.login=adfafdsafasweq3e  -Dsonar.host.url=https://abc.xyz.net -Dsonar.links.scm=https://git.com/abc/sonarqube-example-python.git -Dsonar.projectName=xyz:xyz -Dsonar.projectKey=Sonarqube:Python:integration -Dsonar.branch.name=master -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.c.file.suffixes=- -Dsonar.cpp.file.suffixes=- -Dsonar.objc.file.suffixes=-` the scm link gets added to the sonarqube project.

[image]

How to  link scm with any other  branch than master  on sonarqube?

Comment: In short: you can't. Only one SCM link per project is supported and it is visible on the main branch page.